# Easiest way to plot a T-distribution, mark critical region, and mark T-score in Python

Tags: python, statistics, t-test

What would be the easiest way to plot a T-distribution, shade the critical region, and perhaps draw a vertical line to mark the T-score in Python?

The following will be used as variables:
- Mean
- Degrees of freedom
- Stddev
- alpha
- t-score

Thanks!